# Find Row With Data Between A Range SQL

Tags: sql

I have data following data structure..

```
   _ID             _BEGIN           _END    
    7003            99210            99217        
    7003            10225            10324    
    7003            111111
```

If I get 10323 as input how do I find return row 2 since the number 10323 is between 10225 (_BEGIN) and 10324 (_END) ?

Will the query work if i get 111111 as input will it return row 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where @input between _begin and _end
```

Answer (score 0):

If _begin and _end can be null:

```
select * 
from your_table
where @input between coalesce(_begin,@input) and coalesce(_end,@input)
```