# Search Through All Between Values SQL

Tags: sql

I have data following data structure..

```
   _ID             _BEGIN           _END    
    7003            99210            99217        
    7003            10225            10324    
    7003            111111
```

I want to look through every _BEGIN and _END and return all rows where the input value is between the range of values including the values themselves (i.e. if 10324 is the input, row 2 would be returned)

I have tried this filter but it does not work..

```
where @theInput between a._BEGIN and a._END


--THIS WORKS 
where convert(char(7),'10400') >= convert(char(7),a._BEGIN) 

--BUT ADDING THIS BREAKS AND RETURNS NOTHING
AND convert(char(7),'10400') < convert(char(7),a._END)
```

Comment: What do you get back from your query?  Which database?

Comment: Help us out a bit here - what is @theInput you're querying with? What does the rest of the query look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742523/find-row-with-data-between-a-range-sql

Comment: @theInput is '10226' for example

Comment: To use `between` I believe `@theInput`, `a._BEGIN`, and `a._END` have to be the same type. Are they? You stated that `@theInput` is a `char` datatype.

Comment: yes all fields used are char datatype. Do I have to cast to int or something? If so how?

Comment: `convert(integer, a._BEGIN)`

Comment: @NickLaMarca I do not understand.  How can it be char if they are greater than 255?

Comment: the type of _BEGIN and _END are char(7). So technically a value in _BEGIN could be 'myName1'. The fields should be integer but their not

Comment: If the types are not integer then the comparison is chronological based on the first letter. It means `b...` is between `a...` and `c...`

Comment: So, your initial problem is one of design: you should not have char(7) columns holding values that will always be integers. If you can change the design, you should.

Comment: I cant change the design its a policy thing

Comment: @NickLaMarca What if you put the whole thing in parentheses after your where?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the obvious answer...

```
SELECT * 
FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> a
WHERE @theInput between a._BEGIN and a._END
```

If the data is string (assuming here as we don't know what DB) You could add this.

```
Declare @searchArg VARCHAR(30) = CAST(@theInput as VARCHAR(30));
SELECT * 
FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> a
WHERE @searchArg between a._BEGIN and a._END
```

If you care about performance and you've got a lot of data and indexes you won't want to include function calls on the column values.. you could in-line this conversion but this assures that your predicates are [Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: what software are you using? what version of sql is it?

Comment: I think my problem is the field _BEGIN, _END is of type char. How can I cast it to int or something maybe thats the issue

Comment: @NickLaMarca what SQL are you using? Microsoft? DB2? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: can you show me a convert for mySQL as well as Microsoft? I am not sure the flavor. I am using WinSQL ide if that helps

Comment: convert(integer,_BEGIN) is not working and convert is not highlighted as a keyword

Comment: A quick search indicates that the above should work in MySQL - YOu can execute `SELECT @@VERSION` or `SELECT VERSION()` one should work?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

*Less than* `<` and *greater than* `>` operators work on xCHAR data types without any syntactical error, but it may go semantically wrong. Look at examples:

**1** - `SELECT 'ab' BETWEEN 'aa' AND 'ac' # returns TRUE`

**2** - `SELECT '2' BETWEEN '1' AND '10' # returns FALSE`

Character `2` as being stored in a xCHAR type has greater value than `1xxxxx`

So you should `CAST` types here. [*Exampled on MySQL - For standard compatibility change `UNSIGNED` to `INTEGER`*]

```
WHERE CAST(@theInput as UNSIGNED)
    BETWEEN CAST(a._BEGIN as UNSIGNED) AND CAST(a._END as UNSIGNED)
```

You'd better change the types of columns to avoid ambiguity for later use.

Comment: ...so what if it's based on the "first letter"?  He's dealing with numbers here... how does the point you're making apply here?  Note that the OP has asked a duplicate of his own question, so you should answer there.  Also, the `UNSIGNED` type likely isn't present on all RDBMSs - you'd probably be better served using plain `INTEGER`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I'm pointing out the collation sequence on xCHAR types - in which `SELECT 'a' < 'b'` returns `1`. This applies on `BETWEEN .. AND ..` operator as well. You're right on RDBMSs, but I replied to OP words in comments requesting about MySQL.

Comment: Except you need to mention why that's important for **NUMBERS**.  Just mentioning letters is rather opaque.  You're not even making it clear that this means that `'2'` is thus greater than `'11'`.

Comment: ...except you've explained the _results_ of the process, but not _why_.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM myTable
    WHERE 
    (CAST(@theInput AS char) >= a._BEGIN AND @theInput < a.END);
```

I also saw several of the same type of questions:

[SQL "between" not inclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347649/sql-between-not-inclusive)

[MySQL "between" clause not inclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive)

When I do queries like this, I usually try one side with the greater/less than on either side and work from there.  Maybe that can help.  I'm very slow, but I do lots of trial and error.

Or, use Tony's convert.

I supposed you can convert them to anything appropriate for your program, numeric or text.

Also, see here, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx.
I am not convinced you cannot do your `CAST` in the `SELECT`.

Nick, here is a MySQL version from SO, [MySQL "between" clause not inclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive?lq=1)

Comment: I think my problem is the field _BEGIN, _END is of type char. How can I cast it to int or something maybe thats the issue

Comment: @NickLaMarca You need to tell us what database you are using.  Is it SQL Server with the @?

Comment: convert(integer, a._BEGIN)

Comment: @Tony beat me to it.  I guess I can edit, but would you not cast @theInput?

Comment: Can you please show @Input casted as well as the 2 fields?

Comment: @NickLaMarca I would if I understood better.  I don't understand why you are saying all the values are char when they are above 255.

Comment: the type of _BEGIN and _END are char(7). So technically a value in _BEGIN could be 'myName1'. The fields should be integer but their not

Comment: `convert(integer, @theInput)`, `convert(integer, a._BEGIN)`, `convert(integer, a._END)` but I would make sure that they are all numeric. If they are all char I would probably not convert to int but instead I would convert to varchar(10) or some other number that will not cause truncation, just in case there is a non-numeric character in the string.

Comment: After reading your last comment I would say to cast `@theInput` to `char(7)` by using `convert(char(7), @theInput)`. You might need to `trim` too.

Comment: I added code to the question only part of the filter is working. the < part of the clause is returning nothing when it should return a row